# Ninject transient scope

Tags: ninject

Ninject transient scope applies only once, at the moment a class is constructed:

```
class InjectedClass
{
  [Inject]
  public IClass Instance { get;set;}
}
```

any call to Instance property from an InjectedClass method will refer to same instance of IClass. Is it possible to return a new instance every time? I don't have a reference to IKernel.

Answer (score 2):

In this situation, you want the Factory pattern. Instead of injecting an instance of a type, you inject a factory object and then invoke that method. To use a simple example:

```
 [Inject]
 public ISomeFactory SomeFactory { get; set; }

 public IClass Instance
 {
     get { return SomeFactory.CreateNew(); }
 }
```

Comment: how will the factory create an instance of IClass, should it reference IKernel?

Comment: Please dont replicate the 'magic property that returns a new instance each time' issue - can you please change Instance to a method please? (And I think you should convert it to Constructor Injection too but thats less critical)

Comment: Correct - I was just giving a simple example. The factory pattern is more important.

Answer (score 2):

Load the module from: [Does Ninject support Func (auto generated factory)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4840157/does-ninject-support-func-auto-generated-factory/4851885#4851885)

Then pass a factory function to the constructor:

```
 public ctor(Func<IClass> classFactory)
 {
     this.classFactory = classFactory;
 }
```

And create an instance where required this way:

```
 this.classFactory();
```

NOTE: I think it is not a good design to pass a new instance to others using a property as in your question. If a class that has this one as dependency you should rather use the mechanism from above inside this other class or if only a single instance is required then use constructor injection instead.

Comment: +1 I had queued up a 'task' to answer in the exact same manner!