# Ninject injection into object constructed via reflection

Tags: reflection, ninject

We have hit an issue where we would like to inject a dependency into an object that has been constructed via reflection:

```
        Type _type = Type.GetType(className, true, true);
        ConstructorInfo _ctor = _type.GetConstructor(new[] { typeof(MyClass) });
        IReg _reg = (IReg)_ctor.Invoke(new object[] { _myClass });
```

The injection does not seem to be happening here using property injection. Is it not possible? How can we get around this issue?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do property inject on the object after it's construction via reflection with the  `kernel.Inject(Object)` method on IKernel. But this WILL be post construction and you will not get any constructor injection.

Comment: This seems like the best way so far. But how do I get to my Kernel? Create a new one? It is instantiated at the web service application level (we are using WCF extension). Along with the bindings. And our instantiation logic executes at a business logic level (different assembly) which is unaware it is used by web services.

Comment: The Dependency Injection pattern is a generalization of "classical abstract class factory" + new features(wiring dependencies based on ctor/properties, objects life cycle, ...). So it should be used like a abstract class factories: in setup application (ex: *main* function) you should define "class factory" and pass to component (ex: your business logic assembly) as an abstraction. In our case the abstract class factory is IKernel. How to pass kernel to your to your assembly? pass a instance for each call to business that needs. or define a singleton for it in your business logic assembly.

Comment: You will have to figure out some way to get the kernel. Check out this question for some ideas on legacy systems http://stackoverflow.com/q/6562872/154477

Answer (score 0):

To use the dependency injection framework you shouldn't instantiate object by itself using new or reflection you should call the injection framework. 
In your case:

```
//setup the application
IKernel kernel = new StandardKernel();
//add all your other bindings for property injection
...

kernel.Bind<MyClass>.ToConstant(_myClass); //if same _myClass instance is used than this can go in setup application. 
Type _type = Type.GetType(className, true, true);
var _reg = kernel.Get(_type);
kernel.Unbind<MyClass>(); //cleanup the global kernel
```

Any way the dependency injection framework is used to avoid using reflection for object instantiation + wiring it's dependencies, based on previously configuration (using *Bind* calls for Ninject).

Comment: Unfortunately, there are about 100+ classes that implement that interface. The names of those classes are retrieved dynamically and as a result also instantiated dynamically (see my example above). Which classes need to be instantiated is business logic-dependent and will be pretty difficult to refactor.

Answer (score 0):

There's a `Kernel.Get(Type)`, but as you want to call a specific constructor, it's no use. There is a constructor selection strategy which is customizable, which you could use to emulate what you're doing in your second line.