# What Ninject binding can I use so that one parameter is used in the constructor for another?

Tags: c#, ninject

I have a class like this:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public MyClass(IService service)
    {
        this.Service = service;
        this.Dependency = new Dependency(service);
    }
}
```

I want to move the `new Dependency()` call to the constructor.

```
public class MyClass
{
    public MyClass(IService service, IDependency dependency)
    {
        this.Service = service;
        this.Dependency = dependency;
    }
}
```

I can't work out how to bind it so that the `IDependency` is created with the `service` constructor argument.

```
Bind<IDependency>()
  .To<Dependency>()
    .WithConstructorArgument("service", ctx => ctx.???); // How do I do this?
```

Comment: Dupe of the same question you asked a few hours before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19253827/how-do-i-bind-a-class-which-takes-its-parent-class-in-the-constructor-with-ninje/19253923#comment28502654_19253923

Comment: @Killnine they are similar but different questions. The other one was about `this`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want to have the same instance of `IService` to be ctor-injected into multiple objects. There are 2ways to achieve this:

- scoped binding of `IService`: .InSingletonScope(), InCallScope(), InNamedScope("xyz") etc. (see https://github.com/ninject/ninject/wiki/Object-Scopes)
- implement and use a factory to create `MyClass`. The factory then 1st instantiates `IService` (`IResolutionRoot.Get<IService>();`), and then instantiates and returns `MyClass` using a ctor argument, p.Ex. like this: `IResolutionRoot.Get<MyClass>(new ConstructorArgument("service", service);`

You could also bind IMyClass .ToProvider() and have the provider implement the factory logic to get rid of the extra factory call. But this makes the actual target class binding hard in case u want to bind an interface to multiple classes (with conditions or otherwise). See [How to use a Provider in Ninject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8716258/how-to-use-a-provider-in-ninject)

[Creating an instance using Ninject with additional parameters in the constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2227548/creating-an-instance-using-ninject-with-additional-parameters-in-the-constructor?rq=1) could also be interesting for you.