# How do I bind a class which takes its parent class in the constructor with Ninject?

Tags: c#, ninject

I have a class like this:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public MyClass()
    {
        this.Dependency = new Dependency(this);
    }
}
```

I want to move the `new Dependency()` call to the constructor.

```
public class MyClass
{
    public MyClass(IDependency dependency)
    {
        this.Dependency = dependency;
    }
}
```

I can't work out how to bind it so that the `IDependency` is created with the 'this' constructor argument.

```
Bind<IDependency>()
  .To<Dependency>()
    .WithConstructorArgument("myClass", ctx => ctx.???); // How do I do this?
```

Comment: You can't pass 'this' because 'this' does not exist at the time that the parameter is created.  You only get away with it in the manual case because you create it inside the constructor itself, at which point 'this' has already been created.  In general, this kind of circular reference is a 'code smell' (at least when Dependency is a public class), so you may want to consider whether you can refactor this so that MyClass and Dependency both depend on a separate class that has the necessary shared functionality.

Comment: Not really. I'm refactoring a large existing project and I'm addressing issues one at a time. But I'm not yet clear on the best approach for this one. A more real life example would be a `Contact` which has a `ContactAddress` dependency, (currently instantiated in the constructor), but the address has dependencies so I want to resolve it. I can move `ContactAddress` to use property injection instead of constructor injection, but I'm still not clear on the binding to use.

Answer (score 0):

The way your example is laid out, I think you have that backards. `MyClass` has a dependency on `IDependency`, so I'd expect you to be doing:

```
Bind<IMyClass>().To<MyClass>().WithConstructorArgument("dependency", new Dependency());
```

Comment: I see that I'm in danger of having a circular reference. But my existing `Dependency` class takes a `MyClass` parameter in its constructor. If I want Ninject to handle it, how can I proceed? I could move it to a property and use property injection, but I still don't see how to inject `this` into the constructor.

Comment: Ah, I didn't catch that in your original post. Perhaps you can get rid of the `MyClass` argument in `Dependency`'s constructor and set the reference as a property in `MyClass`'s constructor? (e.g. `dependency.Parent = this;`). Sounds like your classes are pretty tightly coupled, though, and this might just be a bandaid for poor class layout.