# Should an authentication class be static or created from an instance?

Tags: static, ninject

Should an authentication class be static or created from an instance ?

The problem I have is that I cannot access the authentication without injecting an instance of it in any controllers and that a bit problematic.

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    //=> I WANT TO AVOID THIS! <=
    //protected IAuthentification Authentification { get; private set; }  

    //public HomeController(IAuthentification authentification)
    //{
    //    Authentification = authentification;
    //}

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        //Authentification.CreerUtilisateur(new Utilisateur { Nom = "Test", NomUsage = "ttt", MotDePasse = "ddsss" });
        return View();
    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I handle classes with static methods with Ninject?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2710718/how-do-i-handle-classes-with-static-methods-with-ninject)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> that a bit problematic.

What is the problem? What is 'problematic' ? Constructor injection is worth the effort. If not, are you looking for [Property Setter Injection](https://github.com/ninject/ninject/wiki/Injection-Patterns) or [Setter Method Injection](https://github.com/ninject/ninject/wiki/Injection-Patterns) ?

Beware that even if you think they are prettier, the clearest way to manage all of this is simply by using Constructor Injection.

Or is there something I'm missing - you didn't detail your actual problem in the question.

Comment: Method injection fixed my problem. I don't have to write the constructor injection each time.. How can this be a problem ?

Comment: @Rushino: a) Only top level composition root should reference Ninject DLLs b) you might forget to initialize it in tests c) you cant make the backing field readonly. I used to think like you do now but use my refactoring tool to deal with the 'pain'. This means my ctors always always tell me what's required for a class. Having said that, if you are doing this in a more localised context - e.g. just Controllers in your main DLL, it's not the worst possible violation. But having said that, I still wouldnt do it!

Comment: Yeah i see what you mean. I will go with Constructor injection, that will lets me know which commun tools i am using for a specific controller then.

Comment: @Rushino: Also, having it explicit will make it easier to spot when you always have 2 things together, which can often signify a missing abstraction. As long as you have a refactoring tool, it's pretty painless. I had this worked out before the book, but if you have any doubt, can higgly recomend buying http://manning.com/seemann - it covers DI based architecture from top to bottom with superb detail and clarity